# How to edit/load eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to learn about debuggers in eclipse, and in this article:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html

They give a few sample plugins at the bottom that one can install and try out (the zip file on the bottom).

I'm not so familiar with eclipse plugins, and I am unsure as to how to install/view the source code of these jar files in eclipse. I have tried importing them into PDE and that has not worked.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure about the question.

Comment: How do I "try" their sample code?

Comment: Normally you should be able to import it, however I downloaded the sample and had a look at it - neither of the plugin jar files in the zip contain a MANIFEST.MF - basically essential information that Eclipse needs to be able to tell that these are plug-in projects. You might be able recreate this meta data from looking at the content of the jar files, I can try if you can't find another tutorial.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I will try to recreate in the meantime.

Comment: Do you want me to post my recreation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unpack the ZIP file.
2. Unpack each JAR file into it's own directory with:
   jar xf org.eclipse...jar

   One of the unpacked files will be coresrc.zip, which contains the source for the core plugin, and one file will be uisrc.zip, which contains the source for the UI plugin.
3. Unpack those ZIP files somewhere
4. Import the directories created from the ZIP files as plugin projects.

This is not elegant, but will get the source into Eclipse.

It is quite possible that you will not be able to run the plugins, as they've been developed for Eclipse 3.0, which is about 100 years old and pretty much all interfaces have changed since then.